# In windows, npm install express failed, unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js

In windows, npm install express failed, error: unable to verify the first certificate.

so i cannot continue.[the following is the errors snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zqc9.png)

Comment: If you could, please paste the text of the error instead of posting an image of it.

Comment: Thank u . the answer you gived is right .

I'll paste the text of the error next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create a folder where your node project will be stored and then there call the npm install express command !
Pls make sure that you have nodejs installed in your pc !

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
The upstaris is right。

Comment: The answer gived by zero298 is right  : In my command line run:

npm config set strict-ssl false

then,   run:  npm install epress .

finally it is success.